# Why is the type of "this" in a non overriden instance method of child class the parent type?

Tags: c++, inheritance

My C++ is a bit rusty and I'm puzzled by the following sample. The example is short so I think it will be clearer than my explanation, here it is:

```
template <class T>
struct Table
{
    T getCell()
    {
        T c;
        c.setTable(this);
    }
};

struct MyTable;

struct Cell
{
    void setTable(MyTable *tbl)
    {

    }
};

struct MyTable : public Table<Cell>
{

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    MyTable t;
    t.getCell();
}
```

See http://ideone.com/1MhVNc for testing, the compiler says:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘T Table<T>::getCell() [with T = Cell]’:
prog.cpp:30:15:   required from here
prog.cpp:7:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘Table<Cell>* const’ to ‘MyTable*’ [-fpermissive]
prog.cpp:15:10: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Cell::setTable(MyTable*)’ [-fpermissive]
prog.cpp:8:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

I would naivly think than since it is a *MyTable* instance calling **getCell**, "this" in the context of the **getCell** call would have type *MyTable*.

It is apparently not the case, why is that?

Comment: You can convert from a derived class to a base class but not the other way around unless you use a cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. The `static type` is indeed `Table<Cell>`. As you have no virtual methods, you cannot even access the `dynamic type` of `MyTable`.

Consider this: the base class `Table<Cell>` will generate the same code for `getCell` for all instances either directly constructed or as derived types. So how can it depend on the type `MyTable`?

Comment: Of course, thank you. I have been doing way too much PHP lately :)

Answer (score 1):

> I would naivly think than since it is a MyTable instance calling getCell, "this" in the context of the getCell call would have type MyTable.

How is the compiler supposed to know about `MyTable` when it compiles `Table`?

> It is apparently not the case, why is that?

Because it can't be.

`this` is the type of the enclosing class.